# WebDriver cannot connect to Firefox

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Does anyone know the reason for below error log and please help me out to resolve this problem.

```
   [testng] org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7073 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
   [testng] *** LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi: startup
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: /tmp/anonymous486500130836738733webdriver-profile/extensions/webdriver-staging
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Opening XPI database /tmp/anonymous486500130836738733webdriver-profile/extensions.json
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
   [testng] *** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Make addon app-profile:fxdriver@googlecode.com visible
   [testng] *** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes
   [testng] *** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
   [testng] *** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes
   [testng] *** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi: Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Updating add-on states
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Writing add-ons list
   [testng] *** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Starting timer
   [testng] *** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Starting write
   [testng] *** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Write succeeded
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi-utils: XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 15
   [testng] *** LOG addons.manager: shutdown
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi-utils: shutdown
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi: Notifying XPI shutdown observers
   [testng] *** LOG addons.manager: Async provider shutdown done
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi: startup
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: /tmp/anonymous486500130836738733webdriver-profile/extensions/webdriver-staging
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
   [testng] *** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found
   [testng] 
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:250)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:197)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:103)
   [testng]     at com.invient.ui.common.IFTestBase.init(Unknown Source)
   [testng]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
   [testng]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   [testng]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:641)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:609)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1338)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1307)
```

I have searched the solution to either downgrade firefox or upgrade selenium but not succeed.

F.Y.I. :

Firefox version : 26.0
OS : Fedora 18
Selenium version : 2.39.0

Comment: Well it tells you "Application has been upgraded", so why don't you start by upgrading both Firefox and Selenium web-driver to their latest versions?

Comment: Note: the latest version of Firefox 32.0 does not work with the latest WebDriver 2.42.x.